# Может ли мой процесс попасть в другой участок памяти?

Tags: linux, память, безопасность, ос, виртуальная-память

Происходит трансляция адресов через MMU. Получается, в селектор записывается номер дескриптора и смещение, потом в таблице GDT (LDT) находится нужная запись например с правами и прочее, дальше страничное отображение памяти на физическую. А, предположим, я узнал, где у другого процесса что лежит и через селектор сделаю запрос, чтобы он выдал тот участок памяти. Может быть такое или я что-то не понимаю в этой логике отображение виртуального адреса на физический и прав доступа?

Comment: если что, то ни в linux (за исключением совсем древних версий) ни в одной другой современной ОС, GDT полноценно не используется — всё происходит через страничную адресацию...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обращение к виртуальной памяти абсолютно прозрачно для процесса и проходит под контролем ОС, которая просто не даст вам выйти из вашего кусочка памяти. В то же время, любые инструкции CPU, которые могли бы эту прозрачность нарушить являются привилегированными и обычным процессам не доступны.

Однако ОС может нам и помочь. Например, в Linux, если ваш процесс запускается под `root`, есть целых два варианта заглянуть в память другого процесса:

1. Linux предоставляет доступ ко всей физической памяти через устройство `/dev/mem`, с которыми можно обращаться, как с обычными файлами. Таким образом можно сделать полный дамп физической памяти с помощью `dd` и копаться уже в нем.
2. Также Linux предоставляет доступ ко всему виртуальному адресному пространству каждого процесса через файл `/proc/[PID]/mem`, а карта отображения лежит в файле `/proc/[PID]/maps`. Таким образом можно сделать дамп нужной секции или всей памяти отдельного процесса.

---

**Пример**

Напишем небольшую программу, которая будет исполнять роль жертвы:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const char haystack[] = "haystack";

int
main(void)
{
    while (1) {
        puts(haystack);
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Скомпилируем её и запустим:

```bsh
gcc -O0 -g victim.c -o victim && ./victim
```

Она будет выводить строку `haystack` каждые 5 секунд. Теперь давайте попробуем изменить строку, которую выводит жертва путем изменения данных в ее виртуальном адресном пространстве.

Для начала найдем PID жертвы:

```bsh
$ pgrep victim
4595
```

Теперь подключим к запущенному процессу GDB и найдем адрес переменной `haystack`:

```bsh
$ yes | sudo gdb -p 4595 -ex "p &haystack" -ex "quit" | grep haystack
$1 = (const char (*)[9]) 0x558f2b2ae008 <haystack>
```

Теперь самое интересное. Напишем программу, которая будет писать несколько байт по определенному адресу в виртуальном адресном пространстве жертвы. Для этого откроем файл `/proc/4595/mem`, сместимся до нужного нам адреса и выполним `write`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PID "4595"
#define OFFSET 0x558f2b2ae008
#define DATA "dragons"

int
main(void) {
    /* Открываем файл. */
    int f = open("/proc/" PID "/mem", O_WRONLY);

    /* Смещаемся до нужного адреса. */
    lseek(f, OFFSET, SEEK_SET);

    /* Пишем нужные байты. */
    write(f, DATA, sizeof(DATA));
}
```

Если запустить программу под `root` и подождать несколько секунд до следующего вывода жертвы, то увидим что теперь жертва выводит `dragons`. Кажется, у нас получилось?

---

† <sup>Для наглядности сделал скриншот работы программ, который можно найти [здесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41u2z.png).</sup>

‡ <sup>Интересно, что [`man 5 proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html) пишет, что к файлам `/proc/[PID]/mem` можно обратиться только через `open`, `read` и `lseek`, т. е. писать в них нельзя. Видимо, эта страница мануала устарела, потому что запрет на запись в `/proc/[PID]/mem` был отменен в [этом](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=198214a7) коммите ядра. Хотя, может быть, проверку вернули — в общем случае запись в `/proc/[PID]/mem` будет зависеть от версии ядра. Также смотрите [статью](https://lwn.net/Articles/476947/) на LWN про эту уязвимость и связанный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586351/8086115) на SO.</sup>

Comment: Должно вывести `dragonsk`.

Comment: @user207200, в вызове `write` теперь стоит `sizeof` вместо `strlen`, так что после `dragons` запишется `\0`.

Comment: Да, не заметил это изменение.

Comment: @eanmos спасибо, отладчиком мы нашли физический адрес, а изменяем потом  виртуальную память того процесса со значением физического адреса, получается виртуальный и физический совпадают?

Comment: @Venot, нет, отладчиком мы как раз нашли виртуальный адрес. Все что прикладная программа знает о памяти: это её собственное виртуальное адресное пространство. Она как-бы находится в своем "пузыре", выбраться из которого никак не может.

Comment: @eanmos понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не получится. Операционная система при первом обращении к этой памяти перехватит управление и проверит, принадлежит ли она вашему процессу, и если нет - процесс получит `SEGFAULT` и будет прекращен.

Comment: @Venot, любая ОС следит за такими вещами. Хакеры специально уязвимости ищут, чтобы получить доступ к памяти другого процесса. А вы просто так хотите =)

Comment: @gbg а где происходит эта проверка, принадлежит процессу этот участок или нет?

Comment: внутри ОС, это же очевидно. Также процессор немного помогает в этом

Comment: Значит как то можно, но не все так просто)

Comment: в процессорах есть понятия уровней защиты (ring). И обычные приложения работают на обычном уровне, а ядро - там где оно хочет. И просто так переключить уровень защиты нельзя. Но возможно, Вам просто нужно подключится к другому процессу как отладчик и почитать его память